# iOS Charts, line chart doesn't refresh datas

Tags: ios, ios-charts, swift4

I have this problem:
everytime I switch between the segments of the segmented control the datas are messed up, but only if I switch in runtime and only in the 0 segment, the 1 segment works flawlessly no matter how many time I switch. Here's a gif that explains what I mean:

[image]

How to deal with this problem? Here's some code

1. the ibaction func of the segmented control

   ```
   @IBAction func timeSelectionSegControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
   switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
   case 0:
       last7Filler()
   case 1:
       todayFiller()
   case 2:
       last30Filler()
   default:
       break
   } }
   ```
2. `todayFiller()` (the one which works well):

   ```
   func todayFiller() {
   emptyArrays()
   low = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Bassa intensità")
   mid = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Media intensità")
   high = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Alta intensità")

   for i in low {
       if i.date == currentDate() {       //put in arrays xxxA the elements which have the property .date equals to today
           lowA.append(i)
       }
   }

   for i in mid {
       if i.date == currentDate() {
           midA.append(i)
       }
   }

   for i in high {
       if i.date == currentDate() {
           highA.append(i)
       }
   }

   //low severity fill funcs FOR TIME
   if !lowA.isEmpty || !midA.isEmpty || !highA.isEmpty {
       fillBarChart()
       var lowSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceLow = lowA.reduce(into: [String: [Cig]]()) {
           $0[$1.time!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysLow = Array(crossReferenceLow.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysLow {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })

           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no elements found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let indexString = matchingTerms[0]
               let first3 = indexString.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)

               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceLow[first3]?.count)!))
               lowSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
               doubleArray.append(Double(index!))
               doubleArrayMax.append(Double((crossReferenceLow[first3]?.count)!))
           }
       }


       let lowSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: lowSeverityDataEntry, label: "Bassa")
       lowSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.green]
       lowSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       lowSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       lowSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       lowSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       lowSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.green]
       lowSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       lowSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       lowSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false

       //mid severity fill funcs FOR TIME
       var midSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceMid = midA.reduce(into: [String: [Cig]]()) {
           $0[$1.time!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysMid = Array(crossReferenceMid.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysMid {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })

           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no elements found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let indexString = matchingTerms[0]
               let first3 = indexString.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)

               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceMid[first3]?.count)!))
               midSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
               doubleArray.append(Double(index!))
               doubleArrayMax.append(Double((crossReferenceMid[first3]?.count)!))
           }
       }

       let midSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: midSeverityDataEntry, label: "Media")
       midSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.yellow]
       midSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       midSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       midSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       midSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       midSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.yellow]
       midSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       midSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       midSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false


       //high severity fill funcs FOR TIME
       var highSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceHigh = highA.reduce(into: [String: [Cig]]()) {
           $0[$1.time!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysHigh = Array(crossReferenceHigh.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysHigh {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })

           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no elements found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let indexString = matchingTerms[0]
               let first3 = indexString.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)
               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceHigh[first3]?.count)!))
               highSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
               doubleArray.append(Double(index!))
               doubleArrayMax.append(Double((crossReferenceHigh[first3]?.count)!))
           }
       }

       let highSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: highSeverityDataEntry, label: "Alta")
       highSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
       highSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       highSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       highSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       highSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       highSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.red]
       highSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       highSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       highSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false

       let data = LineChartData()
       data.addDataSet(lowSeverityLine)
       data.addDataSet(midSeverityLine)
       data.addDataSet(highSeverityLine)

       lineChartView.data = data

       guard let min = doubleArray.min() else {return}
       guard let max = doubleArrayMax.max() else {return}
       lineChartView.xAxis.axisMinimum = min
       lineChartView.leftAxis.axisMaximum = max
       let myXaxis = lineChartView.xAxis
       myXaxis.granularity = 1.0
       myXaxis.axisMaximum = Double(values.count)
       myXaxis.labelPosition = .bottom
       myXaxis.gridLineWidth = 0.2
       myXaxis.axisLineWidth = 1.0
       myXaxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black
       myXaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: values)

       let yLeftAxis = lineChartView.leftAxis
       yLeftAxis.granularity = 1.0
       yLeftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
       yLeftAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.2
       yLeftAxis.axisLineWidth = 1.0
       yLeftAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black

       lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
       lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
       lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOption: .linear)


   } else {
       lineChartView.noDataText = "Nessuna sigaretta fumata oggi"
       barChartView.noDataText = "Nessuna sigaretta fumata oggi"
   } }
   ```
3. `last7Filler()` func (the one which give me problems):

   ```
   func last7Filler() {
   emptyArrays()
   low = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Bassa intensità")
   mid = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Media intensità")
   high = CoreDataController.shared.loadCigFromSeverityNumber(severity: "Alta intensità")

   for i in low {
       let first3Date = i.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)
       for a in past7Days() {
           let first3Day = "\(a)-"
           if first3Date == first3Day {
               lowA.append(i)
           }
       }
   }
   for i in mid {
       let first3Date = i.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)
       for a in past7Days() {
           let first3Day = "\(a)-"
           if first3Date == first3Day {
               midA.append(i)
           }
       }
   }
   for i in high {
       let first3Date = i.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 3)
       for a in past7Days() {
           let first3Day = "\(a)-"
           if first3Date == first3Day {
               highA.append(i)
           }
       }
   }

   if !lowA.isEmpty || !midA.isEmpty || !highA.isEmpty {

       fillBarChart()
       var lowSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceLow = lowA.reduce(into: [String:[Cig]]() ) {
           $0[$1.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 5), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysLow = Array(crossReferenceLow.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysLow {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })

           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no elements found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceLow[key]?.count)!))
               lowSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
           }
       }

       let lowSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: lowSeverityDataEntry, label: "Bassa")
       lowSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.green]
       lowSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       lowSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       lowSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       lowSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       lowSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.green]
       lowSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       lowSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       lowSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false


       var midSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceMid = midA.reduce(into: [String: [Cig]]() ) {
           $0[$1.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 5), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysMid = Array(crossReferenceMid.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysMid {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })

           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no elements found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceMid[key]?.count)!))
               midSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
           }
       }

       let midSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: midSeverityDataEntry, label: "Media")
       midSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.yellow]
       midSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       midSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       midSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       midSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       midSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.yellow]
       midSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       midSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       midSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false


       var highSeverityDataEntry = [ChartDataEntry]()
       let crossReferenceHigh = highA.reduce(into: [String: [Cig]]()) {
           $0[$1.date!.returnFirstNcharacters(n: 5), default: []].append($1)}
       let sortedKeysHigh = Array(crossReferenceHigh.keys).sorted(by: <)

       for key in sortedKeysHigh {
           let matchingTerms = values.filter({
               $0.range(of: key, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
           })
           if matchingTerms.isEmpty {
               print("no element found in \(key)")
           } else {
               let index = values.index(of: matchingTerms[0])
               let value = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(index!), y: Double((crossReferenceHigh[key]?.count)!))
               highSeverityDataEntry.append(value)
           }
       }
       let highSeverityLine = LineChartDataSet(values: highSeverityDataEntry, label: "Alta")
       highSeverityLine.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
       highSeverityLine.mode = .cubicBezier
       highSeverityLine.lineCapType = self.lineCap
       highSeverityLine.lineWidth = self.lineWidth
       highSeverityLine.circleRadius = self.circleRadius
       highSeverityLine.circleColors = [NSUIColor.red]
       highSeverityLine.circleHoleColor = NSUIColor.white
       highSeverityLine.circleHoleRadius = self.circleHoleRadius
       highSeverityLine.drawValuesEnabled = false

       let data = LineChartData()
       data.addDataSet(lowSeverityLine)
       data.addDataSet(midSeverityLine)
       data.addDataSet(highSeverityLine)

       lineChartView.data = data
       lineChartView.notifyDataSetChanged()
       lineChartView.data!.notifyDataChanged()


       //graphic configuration
       let myXaxis = lineChartView.xAxis
       myXaxis.granularity = 1.0
       myXaxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
       myXaxis.axisMaximum = Double(values.count)
       myXaxis.labelPosition = .bottom
       myXaxis.gridLineWidth = 0.2
       myXaxis.axisLineWidth = 1.0
       myXaxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black
       myXaxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: values)

       let yLeftAxis = lineChartView.leftAxis
       yLeftAxis.granularity = 1.0
       yLeftAxis.axisMinimum = 0.0
       yLeftAxis.gridLineWidth = 0.2
       yLeftAxis.axisLineWidth = 1.0
       yLeftAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black

       lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
       lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
       lineChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOption: .linear)

   } else {
       lineChartView.noDataText = "Nessuna sigaretta fumata nei scorsi 7 giorni"
       barChartView.noDataText = "Nessuna sigaretta fumata nei scorsi 7 giorni"
   }
   ```

p.s. the func `emptyArrays()` just gives `removeAll()` to the arrays `low`, `mid`, `high`, `lowA`, `midA` and `highA`

Comment: Why you are using `Double((crossReferenceLow[key]?.count)` for ChartDataEntry in `last7Filler`?

Comment: @ViniApp because I need to get as y value the amount of the value corresponding to the key, and since the dictionary is not sorted, I create an array of keys sorted in crescent mode (`sortedKeysxxx`) in order to get with `Double((crossReferenceLow[key]?.count)` the right value: for the dictionary maybe I could take elements in random order, but with this method I get the right values in the right order.

Comment: Can you post some sample data for low, medium and high values?